# no output generated in java Decryption code unknown error

Tags: java, performance, web-services, jakarta-ee, encryption

I am not getting any output from this code I passed encrypted text to decrypt ,but the output is unknown, I am not able to find what is wrong with code please help code is posted below

```
private void findMeaning(HttpServletResponse resp,String encryptText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException, 
    NoSuchPaddingException, 
    InvalidKeyException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
    UnsupportedEncodingException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException, 
    BadPaddingException, 
    IOException, ShortBufferException, NoSuchProviderException{ 
       String text = encryptText;
        String secretKey="ezeon8547";

       KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
       SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
        // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
       AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
       //Decryption process; same key will be used for decr
       dcipher=Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
       dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,paramSpec);
       byte[] enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(text);//possible problem here please resolve

       byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(enc);
       String charSet="UTF-8";     
       String plainStr = new String(utf8, charSet);

          sendResponse(resp, "Pincode city:" +plainStr);


    }}
```

i have checked and find when i stop running this code `byte[] enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(text);` then response sent properly,but when this code is participating in a programme the program stop giving output please help about this line of code i am sure problem is with above code

Comment: What do you mean by "out is unknown"? Do you get an exception? Have you checked that `enc` contains the right data (since your comnment suggests that you think there might be a problem)?

Comment: The result is blank no output in printing enc @drunix

Comment: Then you should check if `text`contains the right data.

Comment: That wouldn't help others on SO. Instead I would suggest that you try your example as a java SE app. Replace sendResponse with System.out, remove HttpServletResponse parameter and see if it runs as a plain java program.

Comment: @Drunix i have run this program by removing httpservletresponse and putting system.out.print() in place off sendresponse it works great without any error but when i deploy it google appengine it shows no result

Comment: Ok, this should tell you two things:
1) Your crypto code is correct. 2)
    You have to look after you parameters.

Comment: @drunix i have checked and find when i stop running this code        byte[] enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(text);
 then response sent properly,bt when this code is working in a programme the program stop giving output please help about this line of code i am sure problem is with above code